# Is there an expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-(N^k)}$ in terms of an integer $N>1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, constants, exponential-sum

I was trying to solve for the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$: $\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i; a_i=\frac{2^{-i}}{i}$ and I landed at the inequality $\frac{N-1}{N}\left(S_{n+1}^{(N)}-a_{1}\right)<A_{N^{n+1}}-a_{1}<S_n^{(N)}$, for $N>2$; where $\displaystyle S_n^{(N)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}N^k{a_{N^k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{-(N^k)}$.

Whereas I have since found that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=log2$ I am still curious about the series $S_n^{(N)}$

The series is convergent for all $N\in\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-(N^k)}$$

Is there an expression for it in terms of $N$? If so, what is it and what are the steps to derive it?

Comment: Let $2^{-N} = x$ and consider that $$(1-x)(1 + x + \cdots + x^r) = 1 - x^{(r+1)}.$$  Now consider that $\lim_{r \to \infty} x^{(r+1)} = 0$, for all $x$ such that $|x| < 1.$

Comment: Note, the series diverges for $N = 1$: $2^{-(1^x)} = 2^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, yes it diverges for N=1. I have edited it now to exclude the N=1 case

Comment: @user2661923 I understand how that would work for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {(2^{-N})}^k$, but could you explain how you’d adapt it to suit $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {2^{-(N^k)}}$

Comment: Try using symbolic regression. There's probably not a closed form but if there is that method will likely find it.

Comment: You are right.  My previous comment was in error.  I actually confused $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-(N^k)}$ with $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(2^{-N}\right)^k.$

Comment: Please add some problem context and research as seen in [this question guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @AshwinB Would you like me to add anything else to the answer or answer something else?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I have added context to my question, I hope that is good enough

Comment: @AshwinB [+1] Yes it is good, but does my answer work for you or should I add more?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: I am only looking for a closed form expression out of curiosity. Your answer works for me in the sense that it gives me a direction to proceed towards. I do not need you to add anything more. I might suggest pursuing those upper and lower bounds I provided on $S_{n}^{(N)}$ if you are curious too.

Comment: @AshwinB The notation may be confused with the [**Stirling number** Wolfram notation](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/)? Maybe I will take a look at the limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s try to find a pattern within the series. One way is to use the [**Abel Plana formula**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula). I will replace N with n for simplicity. The result has the [Logarithmic Integral function](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Logarithmic_integral) similar to the gamma function. Note the real and imaginary parts are separated in the end. The [complex argument function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) is also used here:

$$\mathrm{\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-n^k}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n^k}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{{-n^k}\ln(2)}=\frac12 2^{-n^0}+\int_0^\infty 2^{-n^x} dx+i\int _0^\infty\frac{2^{-n^{ix}}-2^{-n^{-ix}}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=\frac14-\frac{li\left(\frac12\right)}{ln(n)}+i\int _0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\left(2^{-e^{-x arg(n)} cos( x log(n))} cos(log(2) e^{-x arg(n)} sin(x log(n))) - 2^{-e^{x arg(n)} cos(x log(n))} cos(log(2) e^{x arg(n)} sin(x log(n)))+ i (sin(log(2) e^{-x arg(n)} sin( x log(n))) (-2^{-e^{-x arg(n)} cos(x log(n)))} - sin(log(2) e^{x arg(n)} sin(x log(n))) 2^{-e^{x arg(n)} cos( x log(n)))}\right)dx}$$

There may exist some other ways of evaluating the result, but this is an integral representation of it. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Note there may be a typo, but sources say this method works.