# Is there an analytic expression for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, theta-functions

In statistical mechanics I often come across average energies of the form:

$$\begin{equation}
\langle\epsilon_n\rangle=\alpha \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2e^{-\alpha n^2}
\end{equation}$$

where $\alpha$ is positive and by rewriting

$$\begin{equation}
\langle\epsilon_n\rangle=-\alpha \partial_{\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha n^2}
\end{equation}$$

However, I cannot seem to solve these kinds of sums. Is there any way to solve the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}$$ analytically?

Comment: See this [fairly similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237148/is-there-an-expression-for-sum-k-0-infty-2-nk-in-terms-of-an-integ/4237672#4237672) please. Also see [Jacobi theta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

Comment: $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (c)^{-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{ln(c)}}-1/2+\frac{ \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\ln(c)}}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-\pi^2 x^2}{\ln(c)}}$$

A horrible [derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700299/a-ramanujan-like-summation-is-it-correct-is-it-extensible/3859675#3859675) Currently looking more into it, and gained a little bit more insight, but here's somewhat of an answer, and can be used as an easy way to get a good estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi yn^2}$ is a *theta* *function*, which arose long ago also in number theory, and as far as I know there is no more-elementary expression for it.

(Despite not being elementary, it does enjoy some interesting properties, useful in number theory, such as the functional equation $f(1/y)=\sqrt{y}\cdot f(y)$, proven via Poisson summation.)